# ActionMailer not sending mail in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I have the following in my config/environments/development.rb

```
  # ActionMailer settings
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    domain: 'gmail.com',
    user_name: 'gmail account',
    password: 'password',
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true}
```

I have the following Mailer and method to test sending an email

```
class EventMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "exmaple@gmail.com"

  def test_email
    mail(to: "Me <myemail@mail.com", subject: 'Test email')
  end

end
```

And inside one of my controller methods I have

```
EventMailer.test_email().deliver
```

I can see in my terminal the message says it's been sent (I believe this is the log?), but I don't receive any actual email. I'm new to the ActionMailer and was just following the steps on the ruby guides site but it doesn't work. Not sure what I'm leaving out. No errors show up in my terminal when I try it out and I know my smtp_settings are correct because I can send emails using rubys Net::SMTP in my ruby interpreter using the same smtp settings as above. I'm just having trouble getting it to work with ActionMailer. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

It was the silliest thing. I just had to restart my local server after I changed the development.rb file >.< gaah